# Unable to access location

Tags: external-hdd

I'm new in Ubuntu. There is an external HDD on my PC. It has two drives Customary and Rakibul. The first one(Customary) works properly but I get an error when trying to get access the second one (Rakibul).

[image: screenshot is here]

Comment: Do you see any messages in `/var/log/syslog` that might explain why the system cannot access the location?

Comment: it says **The device '/dev/sdb3' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
**

Comment: Cool. There you go. If your Windows installation is configured to use "Fast Boot", and this device was connected at the time that Windows shut down, then your partition is in an "unclean state", which means there could be data loss if Ubuntu tries to use it. So, rather than risk losing data, it doesn't let you have it at all.

Comment: how can i fix it